# How to use findstr to search for multiple strings in one line

Tags: string, batch-file, command, findstr

So I want to be able to search for the string "[  FAILED  ]" and the string "." that are both on the same line inside of a text file. How would I do this?

I tried this:

`FINDSTR /C:"[  FAILED  ]" /C:"." output_.txt`

but it produces lines that contain either of the strings. If possible I also want to be able to exclude any lines that contain numbers from my finds.

Answer (score 2):

I have answered my own question using piping and coming up with the following command:

`FINDSTR /C:"[  FAILED  ]" output_.txt | FINDSTR /C:"." | FINDSTR /V [0-9]`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the answer with a single FINDSTR using two regex search strings.

One string looks for `[  FAILED  ]` followed by `.`, and the other looks for `.` followed by `[  FAILED  ]`. Note that `.` and `[` literals must be escaped, and escaping the `]` literal isn't necessary, but it makes the intent more obvious.

```
findstr /r /c:"\[  FAILED  \].*\." /c:"\..*\[  FAILED  \]" output.txt
```

I'm not sure which is faster - one FINDSTR with two search strings, or two FINDSTR joined by a pipe, with one search string each.