# How should I find all the files that contains two strings?

Tags: regex, batch-file, findstr

My problem is to create a batch script file for Windows and iterate through a lot of files and find every file which has a line that contains two specified strings. So if the whole file contains those strings, that's not good enough, they should be at the same line.

For example, I have 5 files which contains the following:

```
1st: apple:green
2nd: apple
green
3rd: green
apple
4th: apple: yellowgreen
5th: apple: green
```

It should return the filenames of the first, fourth and fifth file.

Here is what I have:

```
FINDSTR /s /i /m "apple green" *.txt | FINDSTR "\MyDirectory" >> results.txt
```

How should I modify this to make it work?

Comment: For more solutions see [How to use findstr to search for multiple strings in one line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128009/)

Comment: You should choose the answer which best fitted your question as the accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
findstr /i /s /m /r /c:"apple.*green" /c:"green.*apple" *.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED TO WORK WITH FINDSTR**

This regex worked for me:
`"apple.*green green.*apple"`

Also, your write to file command with the pipe did not work for me (perhaps I'm missing something). If it doesn't work for you, perhaps this will:

`FINDSTR /s /i /m "apple.*green green.*apple" *.txt >> results.txt`